# asp.net mvc deployment giving 403 error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have developed asp.net mvc site in vs 2015 and deployed in iis 7.5 , I am getting 403 access denied error . earlier also I deployed site on same machine successfully but now it is giving 403 access denied. I did the same earlier and it was successful but not now. I have developed site in vs 2013 earlier which was run successfully , for both I have chosen .net 4.0 framework. One more thing my site is deployed like this abc.com/test , here test is alias name of my site when I run it like this it is rendering my default controller and action but when I am mentioned controller and action in url like abc.com/test/account/login , it is giving accesss denied 403 eerror........Any help appreciated